# JAVA Bad variable reference? Receiving strange output - possibly memory address?

Tags: java, pointers

```
public class working {

public static String str = "123zASdcvb/;[";

    public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("!!!"+new LetterInventory(str));
    }

public static class LetterInventory {
    public char[] arr;


    public LetterInventory(String str){
        //Strips our string  of all non alphabetic garbage 
        //and assigns it. This regex removes all non a-z
        //without regard for case of alphabet (?!).
        this.arr = str.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(this.arr); //I want to have it sorted to make my life easier.

        System.out.printf("Our freshly sorted LI is : %s\n",this.toString());
    }


    //Simple enough.
    public String toString() {
        return this.arr.toString();
    }




}
}
```

output:

```
Our freshly sorted LI is : [C@6d69c9a2
!!![C@6d69c9a2
```

What is going wrong here? I walked through my debugger and my array does exactly what I want, it is created, cleaned, and sorted just fine. But everytime I try to print my char[].toString() it comes out screwey. Why so?

Comment: The array does not Override default implementation of Object to string, sou you end up with hash code in result.

Comment: Vash, the page you linked contained my answer. I have flagged my post for deletion.

Comment: You can use `Arrays.toString(arr)` as well.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `toString()` on an array - arrays don't override `toString()`, so you end up with the [implementation from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

As you're dealing with a `char[]`, you should just use the `String` constructor to create a new string:

```
return new String(arr);
```

In other cases you might want to call one of the `Arrays.toString` overloads, to get a comma-separated representation.

It's not clear why you're doing any of this in a constructor yourself, by the way. Your program would be simpler with just a `main` method:

```
// Renamed class to follow Java naming conventions
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "123zASdcvb/;[";
        char[] chars = str.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "").toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        System.out.printf("Our freshly sorted LI is : %s\n", new String(chars));
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work in this case alone as it is a `char` array but in general, `Arrays.toString(arr)` could be used.

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ: Yup, I've edited that in. You almost certainly wouldn't *want* to use `Arrays.toString` in this case though.

Comment: When you've a `char[]`, its always better to use `new String(char)` but I feel the question title doesn't reflect that and for users seeing this in the future, it'd be better that they knew about `Arrays.toString()` which would ease of their task of writing their own method for printing the array. :)

Answer (score 0):

public String toString() {
        return String.copyValueOf(arr);
    }

If you get result  [C@6d69c9a2,it means  it is a array of chars([ for array,c for char) and its hash code is 0x6d69c9a2

Comment: Any reason for preferring a static method call to just calling the constructor here?

Comment: Two ways are similar,just because I post the answer a little bit later...